# Disable keyboard on Android´s webview

Tags: android, webview, android-softkeyboard

I have a Webview and I load on it an url. This url has a form but I don´t want to show the Android´s keyboard when the user clicks to fill the form. I have tried this:

In the activity:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

In the manifest:

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

In the layout:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

and on webview´s properties:

```
android:focusable="false" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Nothing works for me, is there a solution? Thanks

My code is:

```
mWebview  = new WebView(this);


            mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {


                    if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
                        //initiateCall(url);
                        return true;
                    }
                    if (url.startsWith("mailto:")) {
                        //sendEmail(url.substring(7));
                        return true;
                    }


                    return false;
                }


            });




            mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

            mWebview .loadUrl("http://www.myweb.com");
            setContentView(mWebview );
```

Comment: InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)
            getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(webview.getWindowToken(), 0);   just try not sure

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672116/how-disable-softkeyboard-in-webview hope helps you

Comment: did you try my solution below? In my case you can not select any input on the web-page, therefore the keyboard will not appear.

Comment: Where can I put your code in my code? Can you refresh your answer using my code? Thanks very much

Comment: I have already in my code mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(), can I put your onPageFinished method inside?

Comment: I get an error in evaluatejavascript

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you can do something like:

```
mWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            hideSoftKeyboard(View v);
            return false;  
        }     
});
```

And hiding part:

```
public void hideSoftKeyboard(View v) {
    Activity activity = (Activity) v.getContext();
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)  activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

See, if this works..

Comment: On `public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {hideSoftKeyboard(View v); etc etc...` remove View, it becomes: `public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) hideSoftKeyboard(v);`

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit tricky, but generally the programming is such itself ;)
The main idea, that you make with javascript all your editable elements on the web page read only. In my example I made it for `inputs`, but generally you can select everything what you want.

It should work:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        WebView webView  = new WebView(this);
        setContentView(webView);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        final String js = "javascript: var allInputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input'); for (var i = 0, len = allInputs.length; i < len; ++i) { allInputs[i].readOnly = true;}";
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
                    view.evaluateJavascript(js, new ValueCallback<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onReceiveValue(String s) { }
                    });
                } else {
                    view.loadUrl(js);
                }
            }
        });
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.de/");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try to add a focus listener and hide the keyboad when the focus change

```
mWebview.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

        //hide keyboard
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if(null != inputManager && null != getCurrentFocus()) {
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: where I have to put this?

Comment: wherever your webview is.. For example If you webview is in a Fragment you can do this in onCreateView method.

Comment: thanks but not works for me :( , the keyboard appears